# Custom Json Serializer to serialize and deserialize all properties by ignoring the class attributes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I want to serialize all properties of my class but want hide some properties while returning response.

I'm using NewtonSoft.Json.Net for serializing.

For example, in below class I want to serialize both properties but I only want to return PlaceName.

Is there any way to do this?

```
[DataContract]
public class Place
{
   [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
   public int PlaceId { get; set; }

   [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 1)]
   public string PlaceName { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 1:

Below is my current Json File.

```
[
  {
    "placeId": 1,
    "placeName": "Malacca"
  },
  {
    "placeId": 2,
    "placeName": "Kuala Lumpur"
  },
  {
    "placeId": 3,
    "placeName": "Genting Highlands"
  },
  {
    "placeId": 4,
    "placeName": "Singapore"
  },
  {
    "placeId": 5,
    "placeName": "Penang"
  },
  {
    "placeId": 6,
    "placeName": "Perak"
  },
  {
    "placeId": 8,
    "placeName": "Selangor"
  }
]
```

EDIT 2: Found the Solution

I Found the solution with some research.

I've created a custom contract resolver to serialize and deserialize all properties and passed it.

Below is my code

```
public  class AllPropertiesResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.Ignored = false;
        return property;
    }
}
```

And Below is the code where I called it.

```
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new AllPropertiesResolver() });
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stream, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new AllPropertiesResolver() });
```

Thank you all for responding.

Comment: Can you post your json file ?

Comment: May be you can use anonymous class like `return new { PlaceName = place.PlaceName };` ? It's a bit specific solution but anyway...

Comment: @feeeper I'm serializing the objects in a generic class. Mapping each property to an anonymous object is not possible.Still I appreciate suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `[JsonIgnore]`. Since you tagged your question with `asp.net-web-api` I figure that you actually use it. So below is an example where the controller will return the whole model, except properties with [`JsonIgnore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonignoreattribute.htm). By using a custom [`ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) we serializer it to include ALL properties (even though they got `JsonIgnore`). And the use the default `ContractResolver` when returning our response.

But be aware, it will override the default behavior. So you might want to add some other check, than just setting `Ignored = false`;

```
public class PlaceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var json = "[{\"placeId\": 1,\"placeName\": \"Malacca\"},{\"placeId\": 2,\"placeName\": \"Kuala Lumpur\"},{\"placeId\": 3,\"placeName\": \"Genting Highlands\"},{\"placeId\": 4,\"placeName\": \"Singapore\"},{\"placeId\": 5,\"placeName\": \"Penang\"},{\"placeId\": 6,\"placeName\": \"Perak\"},{\"placeId\": 8,\"placeName\": \"Selangor\"}]";

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new IncludeAllPropertiesContractResolver();

        var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Place[]>(json, settings);
        return Ok(places);
    }
}


public class IncludeAllPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        // Or other way to determine...
        foreach (var jsonProperty in properties)
        {
            // Include all properties.
            jsonProperty.Ignored = false;
        }
        return properties;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Place
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 1)]
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
[
{
"placeName": "Malacca"
},
{
"placeName": "Kuala Lumpur"
},
{
"placeName": "Genting Highlands"
},
{
"placeName": "Singapore"
},
{
"placeName": "Penang"
},
{
"placeName": "Perak"
},
{
"placeName": "Selangor"
}
]
```

Or if you don't mind a little reflection. Below we use a `JsonInclude`-attribute, which will override the default behavior of `JsonIgnore`.

```
public class JsonIncludeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        var actualProperties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var jsonProperty in properties)
        {
            // Check if it got our JsonInclude attribute.
            var property = actualProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == jsonProperty.PropertyName);
            if (property != null && property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonInclude)) != null)
            {
                jsonProperty.Ignored = false;
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Place
{
    [JsonInclude] // Will override JsonIgnore.
    [JsonIgnore]
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 1)]
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
}

public class JsonInclude : Attribute
{

}
```

Comment: But using JsonSerializer is not serializing the property. I need to serialize the property. I just don't want to return it in response.

Comment: @SatishKumar - Misunderstood the question, so I updated it.

Comment: I just saw your solution. I've done same thing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SatishKumar - Cool. Glad I could help.

Comment: Also note that, if you inherit something like CamelCaseContractResolver in the second solution it won't work because of casing of property names.
To fix it change the line with this in JsonIncludeContractResolver.CreateProperties method:

var property = actualProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(jsonProperty.PropertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solution is to use anonymous class: `return new { PlaceName = place.PlaceName };`.

Another solution is to create your own serializer for your type and use it for the type. Example for custom serializer you can find [here](http://tinymission.com/post/custom-serialization-for-json-properties-in-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

If you Json output is a `List<Place>` you can try :

```
        var json = "[{\"placeId\":1,\"placeName\":\"Malacca\"},{\"placeId\":2,\"placeName\":\"Kuala Lumpur\"},{\"placeId\":3,\"placeName\":\"Genting Highlands\"},{\"placeId\":4,\"placeName\":\"Singapore\"},{\"placeId\":5,\"placeName\":\"Penang\"},{\"placeId\":6,\"placeName\":\"Perak\"},{\"placeId\":8,\"placeName\":\"Selangor\"}]";

        var Places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Place>>(json);

        foreach (var place in Places)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(place.PlaceName);
        }
```