# How to temporarily disable [JsonIgnore] attribute?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am working on a `ASP.NET WebApi` project. I have a model class that has a property that I don't want to serialize in public calls. For this purpose I am usin `[JsonIgnore]` for that property and it is excluded from jsons as expected. Now in a `[Authorize]` controller method I want to serialize object with all properties, even the one that excluded by `[JsonIgnore]`. Any idae?

Comment: You'll need a custom contract resolver.  This one seems like it should work: [Custom Json Serializer to serialize and deserialize all properties by ignoring the class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40743018).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Json Serializer to serialize and deserialize all properties by ignoring the class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742813/custom-json-serializer-to-serialize-and-deserialize-all-properties-by-ignoring-t)